# grails custom tag puts html tags as String literal

Tags: grails, taglib

I am trying to make simple tag lib:

```
<user:isLoggedIn>
   <a href = "/auth/logout">logout</a>
</user:isLoggedIn>
```

tag lib def:

```
def isLoggedIn = { attr,body ->
        User currentUser = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()

        if(currentUser){
            out << body()
        }   

    }
```

What I see on my page:

```
<a href = "/auth/logout">logout</a>
```

but I was expecting:
[logout](http://Iwasexpectingthisoutputonthepage)

Comment: You can save yourself some work by using `<sec:ifLoggedIn>`. See http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/helperClasses.html#securityTagLib.

Comment: k, I was just exercising but thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this on your `tag lib`  **class** definition remove it.

```
static defaultEncodeAs = 'html'
```

Comment: Why should be remove the "html" encoding?